# Passing properties from custom object to controller returns (null)

Tags: iphone, ios, nsurlconnection, httprequest

I wrote a custom class to handle HTTP requests and in result I would like to get an NSString with BODY for next request but when I try to pass this newly created BODY from this object all I get is (null).

But enough words... Let me show you code:

This is ViewController code

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "HTTPRequestHandler.h"


//Definition of constants for URLs which are being used for requests
#define GET_GRANT_KEY_URL @"http://own-dev1.railwaymen.org:4006/api/get_grant_key"
#define PULL_USER_LOCATIONS_URL @"http://own-dev1.railwaymen.org:4006/api/pull_user_locations"
#define ANCHOR_TERMINAL_URL @"http://own-dev1.railwaymen.org:4006/api/anchor_terminal"

//Definition of constants for first request body
#define GRANT_KEY_BODY @"email=vergun@gmail.com&password=password"
#define PULL_USER_LOCATIONS_BODY @"user_id=b6db2184-8b16-433d-ae21-a9a415d9d4dc&grant_key=2aa1d743e7ebc2b5eb7f278f1da62b30d70c1510"
#define ANCHOR_TERMINAL_BODY @"user_id=b6db2184-8b16-433d-ae21-a9a415d9d4dc&grant_key=2aa1d743e7ebc2b5eb7f278f1da62b30d70c1510&location_id=b91d0894-ce90-47dc-b431-4f67252310f2&client_id=2938472398492&client_secret=017305462947509274"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableString *resultHTTPBody;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (IBAction)makeRequests {
    //First request
    HTTPRequestHandler *getGrantKeyRequest = [[HTTPRequestHandler alloc] initWithURL:GET_GRANT_KEY_URL
                                                                                body:GRANT_KEY_BODY
                                                                      keysToRecievie:@[@"user_id", @"grant_key"]];
    [getGrantKeyRequest makeConnectionWithRequest];

    //Second request
    HTTPRequestHandler *pullUserLocationsRequest = [[HTTPRequestHandler alloc] initWithURL:PULL_USER_LOCATIONS_URL
                                                                                      body:PULL_USER_LOCATIONS_BODY
                                                                            keysToRecievie:@[@"location_id"]];
    [pullUserLocationsRequest makeConnectionWithRequest];

    //Third request
    HTTPRequestHandler *anchorTerminalRequest = [[HTTPRequestHandler alloc] initWithURL:ANCHOR_TERMINAL_URL
                                                                                   body:ANCHOR_TERMINAL_BODY
                                                                         keysToRecievie:@[@"access_token"]];
    [anchorTerminalRequest makeConnectionWithRequest];
}
@end
```

This is .m file from my custrom class

```
@interface HTTPRequestHandler ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSURL *requestURL;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSData *httpBody;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableData *responseData;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *keysToRecieveValues;

@end

@implementation HTTPRequestHandler

- (id)initWithURL:(NSString *)url body:(NSString *)body keysToRecievie:(NSArray *)keys
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        self.responseData = [NSMutableData data];
        self.requestURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:url];
        self.httpBody = [body dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        self.keysToRecieveValues = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:keys];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)makeConnectionWithRequest
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:self.requestURL];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:self.httpBody];
    [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [self.responseData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [self.responseData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    [self setRecievedData:[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.responseData options:kNilOptions error:nil]];
    NSLog(@"%@", [self createNewBodyWithInitializedKeys]);
}

- (NSString *)createNewBodyWithInitializedKeys
{
    NSMutableString *tmpString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];;

    for (NSString *key in self.keysToRecieveValues)
    {
        [tmpString appendFormat:@"%@=%@?", key, [self.recievedData valueForKey:key]];
    }

    [tmpString deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange([tmpString length]-1, 1)];
    return tmpString;
}

@end
```

And, finally, header for HTTPRequestHandler:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface HTTPRequestHandler : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *recievedData;

- (id)initWithURL:(NSString *)url body:(NSString *)body keysToRecievie:(NSArray *)keys;
- (void)makeConnectionWithRequest;
- (NSString *)createNewBodyWithInitializedKeys;

@end
```

I would be very grateful If you can tell me any hints or show my my mistake.

Comment: have you tried logging the responseData?

Comment: Yeah, and what I get is a lot of hex stuff...

Comment: Anything what is HTTPRequestHandler object is passing mi null if I try to Log it. The only exception is when I'm logging it from the inside of the object.

Comment: Try allocating self.recievedData in initURL you are setting the responseData to a non-allocated self.recievedData

Comment: Okey, now I don't have a null but an empty brackets...

Comment: it means that the jsonData you are parsing is has an invalid format and NSJSONSerialization returns a null value. better check where you get your server data and validate the server response

Comment: But how it is possible that description of the recievedData inside the object works fine?

Comment: I tried running your code. these are the values for your receivedData message = "User not found!";status = 0; you are accessing a wrong key in createNewBodyWithInitializedKeys, you were fetching "access_token"

Comment: I create 3 objects of HTTPRequestHandler class and each of it has its own recievedData... But anyway, I cannot pass anything from theses object - That's the big deal.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I checked your url's responses (hope you don't mind) and it seems that the response is not JSON format, that's why the `NSJSONSerialization` returns nil, please check your server response and validate it with an online tool or something to make sure it is a JSON format.

**EDIT**

I know that in xcode 4.4 and above the `@ synthesise` is not needed anymore, but you should anyway add it (just in case) and also, if you declare a property variable you should use it asa a property variable (self.property) unless you are doing some other stuff in the getter method or setter method.

Comment: But NSJSONSerialization works fine and inside I get what I want but I cannot send it outside the object

Comment: Ok, got it and will follow your advices.

Comment: Nope... :( I'm still stuck. I did what @Joshua said and I'm not getting (null) but empty brackets {} - Like there is nothing inside. I guess the problem is with connectionDidFinishLoading: or with createNewBodyWithInitializedKeys. But I cannot find anything on that! I'm confused